Failed to Connect to Another Container in Docker Compose
I have an example of two Web APIs written in .NET 6 and Docker. With the docker-compose.yml configuration below
version: '3.4'

services:
  testmultidocker:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}testmultidocker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: TestMultiDocker\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"


  processing01:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}processing01
    container_name: processing01
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Processing01\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5002:80"

I tried calling from API A to API B using the service name, but it returned an error saying it couldn't be found. As I understand, Docker has created a virtual network to connect the containers, but I still can't connect. Am I missing any steps?

Error:  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
failed because connected host has failed to respond.
(processing01:5002)
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
after a period of time, or established connection failed because
connected host has failed to respond.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16
token)


Probably need to see more details. At the very least, are the apps listening on the ports you're exposing (5000 and 5002)? Can you show minimal code for the apps and how you're starting the containers?

Hi, thank you for comment. App "Processing01" is listen on 5002, i run with docker-compose
Container Port Host Port Host IP Address Port Type
80 5002 0.0.0.0 TCP (IPv4)


As I understand, Docker has created a virtual network to connect the containers, but I still can't connect

Since you have not specified a custom network Docker will use the default one. But AFAIK it still should serve the purpose.

host has failed to respond. (processing01:5002)

You need to use the port inside the container, hence processing01:80. Docker will perform domain name resolution (when calling "from" the Docker managed network) turning processing01 into actual IP, so you will try to connect to 5002 port inside the container, while app listens to 80.
5002:80 will map 5002 port on the host, so something like host.docker.internal:5002 (or localhost:5002 when calling from the host) should work (see I want to connect from a container to a service on the host section of the docs, also previously out of the box it was not working at all OS).
Another note - use the depends_on attribute, since otherwise the called service can be in process of starting up and not ready to serve the requests.
See also the Docker: Networking overview docs.
